# Upgrading EF7 to beta 6

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm currently using EF7 - beta4 and would like to use beta6. I know I'm playing with fire by using nightlies, but has anyone else done this and have been able to build after upgrading?

I've added the nightly nuget repository: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/ but when ever I upgrade a package it totally trashes all of .net in both DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5. Now I'm not crazy enough to do this in a working project, so I'm testing this out in new empty mvc project and when I attempt to build I get in excess of 2000 errors from everything.

Has anyone else attempted this and if so how does one get around all the errors?

Answer (score 1):

The nightly builds are highly unstable. Here are some pointers for working on the bleeding edge of ASP.NET.

1. Reset all packages. Sometimes nightly builds break other packages. Delete `project.lock.json` and delete all packages (`~/.dnx/packages/`). Reinstalling may help you get a coherent set.
2. Upgrade DNX. `dnvm upgrade -u`. This installs the latest, **unstable** version of DNX.
3. Submit [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/entityframework/issues). If it's breaking for you, it may not just be you.
4. Pay attention to the [ASP.NET on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet). Nightly builds are usually only a few days behind the latest changes to the `dev` branch. We are working fast, and breaking things.
5. If stability is important, stick to the Nuget.org betas. Beta5 was just released yesterday, and has been more thoroughly vetted for stability.
6. Watch the [Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements) repository to receive a heads-up on breaking changes.